# difference in number of variables in train and test

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have a training dataset with the following variables

```
> names(train)

[1] "id"          "user_id"     "campaign_id" "send_date"   "is_open"    
[6] "is_click"
```

1 more dataset called 'campaign' with the following

```
> names(camp)

[1] "campaign_id"          "communication_type"   "total_links"         
[4] "no_of_internal_links" "no_of_images"         "no_of_sections"      
[7] "email_body"           "subject"              "email_url"
```

test dataset as below

```
> names(test)

[1] "id"          "campaign_id" "user_id"     "send_date"
```

I have used left join to combine train and camp based on 'campaign_id' in the 2 datasets.

The resultant dataset is named 'left' and it has the below variables:

```
> names(left)

 [1] "id"                   "user_id"              "campaign_id"         
 [4] "send_date"            "communication_type"   "total_links"         
 [7] "no_of_internal_links" "no_of_images"         "no_of_sections"      
[10] "email_body"           "subject"              "email_url"           
[13] "is_open"              "is_click"
```

The dimensions of the datasets are as below respectively:

```
> dim(train);dim(camp);dim(left);dim(test)

[1] 1023191       6
[1] 52  9
[1] 1023191      14
[1] 773858      4
```

I ran a logistic regression on the dataset 'left' excluding the variables "id" and "campaign_id" as per the requirement. "is_click" being the class variable.

```
model <- glm(is_click ~., data = left[, !names(left) %in% c("id", "campaign_id")], family = binomial)
```

The model ran successfully. But when I try to predict the test dataset using predict function it gives out an error as the test dataset doesn't have all the variables in the dataset on which the model was trained - 'left'

```
> predict1 <- pglogis(predict(model, test))
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  object 'communication_type' not found
```

I am expecting the output to contain the variables "id" and "is_click". "is_click" being the class variable, I would like to see it as 0 for probability < 0.5 and as 1 for probability > 0.5

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: dont you need to left join the camp dataset to your test? you cannot predict for your test set if it does not contain All the variables that were present in your train.

Comment: In addition to Varun's comment, you do not show what `test` looks like.

Comment: I have added a code that show column names of 'test' dataset in my original question.

Comment: @VarunRajan: are u suggesting to left join my dataset used for training the model with the test dataset and then running predict on the test ?

Comment: umm you have 3 datasets i presume. the test simply does not contain the 2 dependant variables (not sure why you have both in the same model, create two for each?) your camp contains additional information about the whole train and test i assume. unless you have a separate camp dataset specifically for the test records, you need to add those features to your test as well.

Comment: thnx a lot varun... I did just that. I was able to run the model and predict the test data. but not getting the desired results.. I will check and get back to you..